# The Android OS in the Emulator freezes and is unusable afterwards

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I can start the Emulator and it starts the Android OS good and in 60 fps. However, shortly after the start of the Emulator, Android just freezes (not the Emulator) and is unusable.

I find this error code in the Event Log: `Emulator: error deleting WGL context! error 0x6` and this in the `idea.log`:

```java
Process hasn't generated any output for a long time.
If it's a long-running mostly idle daemon process, consider overriding OSProcessHandler#readerOptions with 'BaseOutputReader.Options.forMostlySilentProcess()' to reduce CPU usage.
Command line: C:\Users\ARES\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapstorage -avd Pixel_2_API_29 
java.lang.Throwable: Process creation:
[...]
```

This started happening after I installed Android Studio on Windows 10 after reverting the OS from Ubuntu. On Ubuntu, everything ran fine.

EDIT: I found out that only the first start after Windows boot works properly. Any other starts in the same Windows session produce this error.

Comment: I´am facing the same issue... hours and hours of research on internet and no solution... have you discovered what happens?

Comment: @charli3B I don't know if I fixed it back in the day. It is working now on Windows 10. But back then, I explored some Linux distributions and therefore swapped my OS a dozen times. I landed back on Windows 10 because those distribution's UI/UX was dogshit. So you might want to simply reinstall your Windows 10.

Comment: I keep having the same problem on Windows 10... I've tried everything, but nothing.